# Google Analytics Event Tracking not Appearing in Real Time

Tags: google-analytics

This event and all `onclick` events like it are not tracking in Google Analytics Real Time.  Any idea why not?

```
<a href="mailto:email@domain.com" class="white" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Connect', 'Submit', 'Value Goes Here');">email@domain.com</a>
```

This is not specific to `mailto` links.  This is for any link where I'm trying to use `onclick` event tracking.

In case you're wondering I do not have an IP filter set.

Comment: Are you able to see you own visit in RT? Do you have the analytics.js snippet on your page? Are you using GTM? Code looks fine. Try to install GA Debugger to analyse the hit, to see if there is any issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

We're using gatag.js (newer version of ga.js). I was still using the syntax from ga.js  The syntax for tracking an event is slightly different in the newer gatag.js.  That was my issue.

Comment: Whoops... I'm sure Google maintaining multiple versions of legacy documentation doesn't confuse people at all...